# JavaScript text form validation from another field being updated by same form

Tags: javascript, html

I created below form: when you enter a name in first text box, it dynamically adds the names to another field below after pressing the + button. The function is implemented on the + button.

Now I want to add a validation logic within the same script, so that same name shouldn't be added twice. Please advise, only want to implement using javascript.

```js
    function promptAdd(list){
    var text = "";
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        text += inputs[i].value;
        }
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    li.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-1">
        <div class="card h-100 text-left">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Add Resources</h4>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                <small id="message" class="form-text text-muted">Press + to add to your list</small>
                <button id="bd1" class="btn add-more" onclick="promptAdd(list)" type="button">+</button>
                <br></br>
                <h5>List of Resources added</h5>
                <div class="form-control" id="list">
                    <span id="list">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have access to es6? this can easily be done using Sets.  if not, just use `indexOf` to see if a value already exists, and only insert if not.  You will have to keep a list of what's already there or parse the list each time though.

Comment: Your best bet would be to maintain an array of the items. Then it will be super easy to look in the array to see if an item already exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation could be implemented simply by looping through all the `li`'s and comparing the text of every `li` with the value of the `input` and if the values matches just return `false`, like :

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  if (lis[i].innerText == text) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function promptAdd(list) {
  var text = "";
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    text += inputs[i].value;
  }
  
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (lis[i].innerText == text ){
      resetInputs();
      
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    
  li.appendChild(node);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  
  resetInputs();
}

function resetInputs(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-1">
    <div class="card h-100 text-left">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Add Resources</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" placeholder="Enter Name" />
        <small id="message" class="form-text text-muted">Press + to add to your list</small>
        <button id="bd1" class="btn add-more" onclick="promptAdd(list)" type="button">+</button>
        <br><br>
        <h5>List of Resources added</h5>
        <div class="form-control" id="list">
          <span id="list"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, another QQ. I am also trying to reset the Enter name form field after adding the name using .reset() method; any advise where I should add.

Comment: Glad i could help, you could use `.value = "";` instead, check my update

Answer (score 1):

Loop though all `li` elements and check their `innerText` with the new text.
If you want to ignore capitalization you can use `innerText.toUpperCase() === newText.toUpperCase()`

```js
function promptAdd(list) {
  var text = "";
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    text += inputs[i].value;
  }

  if (textAlreadyExistsInList(text)) {
    return;
  };

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var node = document.createTextNode(text);
  li.appendChild(node);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
};

function textAlreadyExistsInList(text) {
  var itemExists = false;
  var items = document.getElementById("list").querySelectorAll('li');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].innerText === text) { //to ignore casing: items[i].innerText.toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase()
      itemExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return itemExists;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-1">
    <div class="card h-100 text-left">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Add Resources</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" placeholder="Enter Name" />
        <small id="message" class="form-text text-muted">Press + to add to your list</small>
        <button id="bd1" class="btn add-more" onclick="promptAdd(list)" type="button">+</button>
        <br></br>
        <h5>List of Resources added</h5>
        <div class="form-control" id="list">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one input text so given that id is better . Here I set `insert_name` as id ! Get all li by `querySelectAll` and check text with `innerHTML` and input value .

```
function promptAdd(list){
    var inputs = document.getElementById("insert_name").value;
    if(checkDuplicate(inputs)) return; // check duplicate
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(inputs);
    li.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
function checkDuplicate(name) {
    var flag = false;
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for(var i = 0 ;i < lis.length;i++) {
        if(name == lis[i].innerHTML) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```